# How to get selected rows of a grid panel in ExtJs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to get the surname fields of the selected rows.
This one does not work at all:

> users.getSelectionModel().getSelections();

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about `users.getSelectionModel().getSelection();` ?

`getSelections()` was used in ExtJS3. In ExtJS4, they decided to improve grammar a little it seems: [ExtJS4 docs for Ext.selection.Model](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.selection.Model)